# Understanding the encryption type

Tags: php, encryption, decode

Can any one help me to find out the encryption method of the following code ?

```
<?php $OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0'].=$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']{7}.$OOO000000{5};$GLOBALS['OOO000O00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};$GLOBALS['O0O000O00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};$GLOBALS['O0O000O00']=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};$GLOBALS['O0O00OO00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};$GLOBALS['OOO00000O']=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0x3140;eval($GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kR0xPQkFMU1snT09PMDAwTzAwJ10oJE9PTzBPME8wMCwncmInKTskR0xPQkFMU1snTzBPMDBPTzAwJ10oJE8wMDBPME8wMCwweDVkYyk7JE9PMDBPMDBPMD0kR0xPQkFMU1snT09PMDAwME8wJ10oJEdMT0JBTFNbJ09PTzAwMDAwTyddKCRHTE9CQUxTWydPME8wME9PMDAnXSgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4NDcwKSwnSnp2V2c0ZFBFOStmVGFrc294NU15T2oxTE5ibXVTQTNVaGVpRnFubHdDMkR0OHIvUVpjcEhZNjdWMFJHQklLWD0nLCdBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1Njc4OSsvJykpO2V2YWwoJE9PMDBPMDBPMCk7'));return;?>io~\XM^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TzidR\nXl
```

Comment: I can't read your example because it's one really long line, but it looks like the end of it is [base64](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Comment: its obfuscation, not encryption. usually seen in either 'hack' scripts or third-party modules\add-ons - in either case ask who did it, not us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two parts. First sets up GLOBALS so it includes:

```
[OOO0000O0] => base64_decode
[OOO000O00] => fopen
[O0O000O00] => fgets
[O0O00OO00] => fread
[OOO00000O] => strtr
```

This means the top bit turns into:

```
base64_decode('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kR0xPQkFMU1snT09PMDAwTzAwJ10oJE9PTzBPME8wMCwncmInKTskR0xPQkFMU1snTzBPMDBPTzAwJ10oJE8wMDBPME8wMCwweDVkYyk7JE9PMDBPMDBPMD0kR0xPQkFMU1snT09PMDAwME8wJ10oJEdMT0JBTFNbJ09PTzAwMDAwTyddKCRHTE9CQUxTWydPME8wME9PMDAnXSgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4NDcwKSwnSnp2V2c0ZFBFOStmVGFrc294NU15T2oxTE5ibXVTQTNVaGVpRnFubHdDMkR0OHIvUVpjcEhZNjdWMFJHQklLWD0nLCdBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1Njc4OSsvJykpO2V2YWwoJE9PMDBPMDBPMCk7')
```

Then this code is constructed:

```
$O000O0O00=$GLOBALS['OOO000O00']($OOO0O0O00,'rb');
$GLOBALS['O0O00OO00']($O000O0O00,0x5dc);
$OO00O00O0=$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']($GLOBALS['OOO00000O']($GLOBALS['O0O00OO00']($O000O0O00,0x470),'JzvWg4dPE9+fTaksox5MyOj1LNbmuSA3UheiFqnlwC2Dt8r/QZcpHY67V0RGBIKX=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'));
```

which in turn constructs:

```
$O000O0O00=fopen($OOO0O0O00,'rb');
fread($O000O0O00,0x5dc);
$OO00O00O0=base64_decode(strtr(fread($O000O0O00,0x470),'JzvWg4dPE9+fTaksox5MyOj1LNbmuSA3UheiFqnlwC2Dt8r/QZcpHY67V0RGBIKX=','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'));
eval($OO00O00O0);
```

This reads the file we are in, trims it and uses that bit of txt after the ?>.

After slightly more mangling this gives us some legit looking code for a function that deals with some ecommerce platform. It assumes a global variable called $cookie, and requires a class called Tools. The code doesn't look malicious.

Quite a neat bit of obfuscation, but as with all code mangling in PHP you can't do a huge amount at the end of the day to stop the code being read as the interpreter needs to be able to understand what it's meant to do!

Regarding the question – you could quite easily do this yourself – it may well have been done by hand as there are only 2/3 levels of obfuscation (you might expect a tool to go through many more). In addition everything needed is in the code – for a tool you might want to have a decryption key that is fetched only if the IP and hostname match a whitelist then cached.